# Problems getting touch event on UIImageView in iOS 5

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have problems detecting touch events on my UIImageView. I have sub classed UIImageView and overrided canBecomeFirstResponder, touchedBegan and touchesEnded:

```
@implementation ImageViewNext

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches Began event");
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches Ended");
}
```

I have ensured that all the parent views have User Interaction Enabled.

But I don't get my events?

I have tried to find the solution here but without any luck. But in my search I found that some people use "UIGestureRecognizer" to get the same effect. So as a side question, what is the "right" solution use the override method or use UIGestureRecognizer? I don't like the solution where a normal button is given an image, so please keep those post away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `initWithFrame:` is called? UIViews have two designated initializers, `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder`, depending on how they are created.

Comment: You're right initWithFrame: isn't called! Thanks That's fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're not getting the touch events, but to answer the other part of your question using a UIGestureRecognizer will significantly simplify your touch handling for any of the gestures for which there's a recognizer available. It's much simpler to use and you'll need less code.

Furthermore, if in the future you need to negotiate between different touch events (is it a tap of a drag type questions) then all that logic is handled trivially.